# Shopping cart can't hold currently items when I go back to the menu page and add a new items

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created a shopping cart application, and it can add items to the cart. But the issue is it can't add another new item when I go back to the menu page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkxob.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Gh4.jpg

So, it worked for the first time when I added: "Ice Coffee for 3 and Red Tea for 2" to the cart.

Then when I go back to the menu page and add another new item: "Black Tea for 5, and Green for 2".Then the new items can be added to the cart. But for the "Ice Coffee and Red Tea" was changed the quantity to 1. It can't keep the last quantity. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2fcC.jpg

How can I fix this issue so that it can hold the current items of the quantity, and add another new item when I go back to the menu page?

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView cartListView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cart_delete_item:
            Main.getAddedItems().clear();
            Toast.makeText(this, "The cart has been cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CartAdapter cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(this, getOrganizedAddedItems());
            cartListView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);   //HW log---Yes or No
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    cartListView = findViewById(R.id.cart_listView);

    CartAdapter cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(this, getOrganizedAddedItems());
    cartListView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
}

private List<CartItem> getOrganizedAddedItems() {
    List<com.example.shoppingcar.MenuItem> addedItems = Main.getAddedItems();
    List<CartItem> organizedAddedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    int quantity = 1;
    double totalPrice;

    for (int i = 0; i < addedItems.size(); i++) {
        com.example.shoppingcar.MenuItem currentMenuItem = addedItems.get(i);
        for (int y = i + 1; y < addedItems.size(); y++) {
            if (currentMenuItem.getName().equals(addedItems.get(y).getName())) {
                quantity++;
                addedItems.remove(y);
                y--;
            }
        }
        totalPrice = currentMenuItem.getPrice() * quantity;
        organizedAddedItems.add(new CartItem(currentMenuItem.getName(), quantity, totalPrice));
        quantity = 1;
    }
    return organizedAddedItems;
}
```

}

I think I need to create a method or something else to hold this method of `private List<CartItem> getOrganizedAddedItems()` But I don't know which method can work, and where I need to put the new method into the code. I mean do I put the new method inside of that `private List<CartItem> getOrganizedAddedItems()` or inside of `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Can someone help me with this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That `private List<CartItem> getOrganizedAddedItems()` and `onCreate()` are both methods themselves, so you wouldn't be adding a method inside them. It looks like you're making a ListView, and adding rows to that, with each row containing a CartItem object.

If that is correct, then this nested for loop

```
for (int y = i + 1; y < addedItems.size(); y++) {
        if (currentMenuItem.getName().equals(addedItems.get(y).getName())) {
            quantity++;
            addedItems.remove(y);
            y--;
        }
    }
```

is unnecessary and you could just use something like:

```
for( MenuItem currentMenuItem : addedItems ){
   totalPrice = currentMenuItem.getPrice() * currentMenuItem.getQuantity();
    organizedAddedItems.add(new CartItem(currentMenuItem.getName(), quantity, totalPrice));
}
```

This would require a small change to the Menuitem, to add a quantity parameter to it which can be initialized to 1 and changed as needed. In return this will give you easier access to setting and retrieving quantities, no new methods needed, and as a bonus eliminate the need for nested for loops which will improve your performance (granted, pretty slight in this case, but still better practice).

For the last paragraph of your question, this seems to be a separate issue but it's not quite clear what you are asking, and you will need to add more details as to how you are storing the list of CartItem as opposed to the MenuItem and what you are trying to achieve to get more help.

Additionally, you could possibly be simplifying your code further, by removing the CartItem altogether, and simply keeping a single class variable tracking the total price for all the objects instead, but again, to know for sure you would have to describe the structure of your code further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, could you mark approved, and otherwise could you clarify what else you are looking for?